# Improve prevent php script run twice (with cronjobs)

Tags: php

I'm like to improve script below, or maybe know if exist a better way to rewrite to better results.

I use this on two files cron1.php and cron2.php executed every 5 seconds and need to prevent running twice.

Script execution time depends of filesize, most of the time took around 2 seconds, but for huge files can take 25/30 seconds, for this i need to stop execution.

I'm on right way? Any suggestion to improve?

```
$fp = fopen("cron.lock", "a+");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB))
{
  echo "task started\n";
  // Here is my long script
  // Cron run every 5 seconds
  sleep(2);

  flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
}
else
{
    echo "task already running\n";
    exit;
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Just update a database table field to "started" when a cronjob is started and update it to "ended" when it is finished. So next time if you run the cronjob just check whether the field value is "ended" (if so, run it, else do nothing) - then set the cronjob to run say every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I generally do a file operation like dumping the `getmypid` in the lock file. So externally I can know which pid has locked it. In some debugging cases, that is helpful.
Finally, `unlink` the lock file when you are done.